# A cartoon series about teenage monsters including a one-eyed mummy girl

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This is a show from my childhood I only saw two episodes of.

It's a show about teenagers who are also monsters and I'm pretty sure the main character was a girl. The show I'm talking about isn't *Ruby Gloom*.

The main character had a friend who was a one-eyed mummy girl.
What I mostly remember about the show is that one girl that was a mummy and she had one eye.

There was an episode were they were trying to find a new actress who has one eye so the main character thought that her friend the mummy girl was her or is a descendent of her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were a child, so approximately what year would you have seen this?

Comment: actually, I'm 20 years old

Comment: So you would have seen this about 10-ish years ago, maybe between 2010 and 2015?

Comment: I guess 2015 I'm pretty sure I saw the show ether in 2010 or 2015 the show kinda looked like a 2000s cartoon